# Trying to use mirror for pacman (mingw64) but it cant find db file on servers

Tags: windows-7, mingw

This is my problem:

Im trying to compile gEDA (pcb-creator) on Win7 and troubleshoot the upcomming errors. Currently Im stuck at this one, returned from `./configure`:

> Cannot find gdlib-config.

and as `pacman -Ss gdlib` doesnt return anything, i tried to find a mirror that has it. There is this [mirror-list](https://www.archlinux.org/mirrors/status/) but all mirrors listed there lack the **mingw64.db** which seems to be expected if i add the mirrors URL to the **\etc\pacman.d\mirrorlist.mingw64** file.

So, how do I tell pacman to use the repository if there is no **mingw64.db** file? Or – what might be – if im doing it wrong: how do I do it?

Answer (score 1):

First, just because MinGW and Arch Linux use the same pacman, doesn't mean they use the same mirrors. Only the tool is the same (just like with Debian vs Ubuntu, etc.) but the actual packages and their locations differ.

That said, the correct mirrors are probably already configured in MinGW's stock pacman.conf and you might only need to tell pacman to *download* the databases using `pacman -Sy`.

Comment: i tried `pacman -Sy`, but that doesnt bring gdlib-config into my database. on the other hand, at the ArchLinux Mirrors, they have it, but i cant configure pacman to use them.

Comment: The Arch Linux mirrors will be useless because they only contain packages built for Linux (x86 and x86_64), not for Windows.